# Download file matching filename with largest number

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to download in python a file from an index directory that matches a pattern "foo_14_bar.dat" but where I download only the one with the largest number in the place of 14.

For example, if there were several files in the directory:

- "asdf_234_asdf.dat"
- "foo_21_bar.dat"
- "foo_9_bar.dat"

I would download the second file.

How can I accomplish this? It seems like beautiful soup with urllib2 would be useful, but I can't quite think of how to implement it.

**Edit**: Should I first get a list of text that matches the pattern, and then find the largest number, and then download it? Or is there a better/cleaner way?

Answer (score 1):

Going to use requests and beautifulsoup4 for this.

Install them like so:

```
sudo pip install requests
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Here is the script that we will use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL of your Index directory
url = 'https://example.com/open_dir/'

# Delimiter to parse files
delimiter = '_'

# Issue a GET request to the URL, exit if an error occurs
try:
    r = requests.get(url)
except Exception as e:
    print '[-] Error: %s' % str(e)
    sys.exit(1)

# Take the HTML response and put it in BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

# Create an empty files list
files = []

# Parse the HTML, make sure you read the BeautifulSoup docs
for table in soup.findAll('table'):
    for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
        for td in table.findAll('td'):
            for a in td.findAll('a'):
                if a['href'] not in files:
                    if not a['href'].endswith('/'):
                        files.append(a['href'])

# Make sure files list is not empty
if not files:
    print '[-] Error: no files found'
    sys.exit(1)

# You will see what we do with these
filename = ''
largest = 0

for f in files:
    try:
        fParts = f.split(delimiter)
        number = fParts[1]
        if number > largest:
            filename = f
            largest = number 
    except Exception as e:
        print '[-] Error, file probably doesn\'t match pattern: %s' % str(e)

print '[+] Largest file: %s' % filename
```

Tested and working.